# Font not embedded: how to fix accessibility issue in PDF?

Tags: java, pdf, itext, accessibility

I created my PDF with iText 4.2.1.
When I upload the file to PAC2021 (PDF Accessibility Checker 2021) I get the "font not embedded" warning.

[image]

The error is not on the text, but on two points of the PDF and I don't understand the meaning.

I set the font like this:

```
String font = "/fonts/FreeSans.ttf";
FontFactory.register(font, "MYFONT");
Font fontOne = FontFactory.getFont("MYFONT", BaseFont.WINANSI, true, 12, Font.BOLD);
Font fontTwo = FontFactory.getFont("MYFONT", BaseFont.WINANSI, true, 10, Font.BOLD);
Font fontThree = FontFactory.getFont("MYFONT", BaseFont.WINANSI, true, 10);
```

Any suggestions?